# Reset value of disabled Formik Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to clear/reset the value of a checkbox switch after it becomes disabled. I initially thought I had achieved this by using a React conditional and setting the value to an empty string but if the checkbox had been activated prior to being disabled then that value still gets submitted. This behaviour doesn't seem correct as I was under the impression that disabled input field values do not get submitted?

The React conditional says that if the form is disabled then the value of the checkbox should be empty.

I am using Formik to process forms with Yup schema validation.

Below is my entire code for the form.

Thank you, in advance.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import Router from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
import Error from "../components/error";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";

var instagram = false;
var twitter = false;
var github = false;

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  firstName: Yup.string()
    .max(15, "Must be 15 characters or less"),
  email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("Required"),
  username: Yup.string()
    .test(
      'valid-instagram', "Instagram: may contain only alphanumeric characters, periods, and underscores", function (username){
        var instagramRegex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/);
        var instagramRes = instagramRegex.test(username)
        if (instagramRes) { // if res is true then the username is valid and the switch can be enabled
          instagram = false;
          return true // return true to tell Yup the field is valid
        } else {
          instagram = true;
          return true // true removes error message
        }
      }
    )
    .test(
      'valid-twitter', "Twitter: may only contain alphanumeric characters or underscores", function (username){
        var twitterRegex = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$/);
        var twitterRes = twitterRegex.test(username)
        if (twitterRes) { // if res is true then the username is valid and the switch can be enabled
          twitter = false;
          return true // return true to tell Yup the field is valid
        } else {
          twitter = true;
          return true // true removes error message
        }
      }
    )
    .test(
      'valid-github', "GitHub: may only contain alphanumeric characters or single hyphens", function (username){
        var githubRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-z\d](?:[a-z\d]|-(?=[a-z\d])){0,38}$/i);
        var githubRes = githubRegex.test(username)
        if (githubRes) { // if res is true then the username is valid and the switch can be enabled
          github = false;
          return true // return true to tell Yup the field is valid
        } else {
          github = true;
          return true // true removes error message
        }
      }
    )
    .required("Required"),
  acceptTerms: Yup.boolean()
    .required("Required")
    .oneOf([true], "You must accept the terms and conditions."),
  switchGroup: Yup.array().required("At least one option must be selected"),
});

const initialValues = {
  firstName: "",
  email: "",
  username: "",
  acceptTerms: false, // added for our checkbox
  switchGroup: [], // array for switches
};

export default function Signup() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>Signup - Notify.is</title>
      </Head>

      <div className="container-center">
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            const data = new URLSearchParams(values);
            const res = await axios
              .post("http://localhost:8080/api/signup", data)
              .then((response) => {
                Router.push("/thanks");
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                setError(error.message);
              });
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
          {({ touched, errors, isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form className="form">
              <h1 className="display-4 pb-3">Get notified</h1>

              <div className="form-label-group">
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  name="firstName"
                  id="firstName"
                  placeholder="First name"
                  className={`form-control ${
                    touched.firstName && errors.firstName
                      ? "is-invalid"
                      : null
                  }`}
                />
                <label htmlFor="firstname">First name</label>
                <small id="nameHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                  Optional
                </small>
              </div>

              <div className="form-label-group">
                <Field
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  id="email"
                  placeholder="Email address"
                  className={`form-control ${
                    touched.email && errors.email ? "is-invalid" : null
                  }`}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="email"
                  className="invalid-feedback"
                />
                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                  We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                </small>
                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-label-group">
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  id="username"
                  autoCorrect="off"
                  autoCapitalize="none"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  className={`form-control ${
                    touched.username && errors.username ? "is-invalid" : null
                  }`}
                />
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="username"
                  className="invalid-feedback"
                />
                <small id="usernameHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                  The unavailable username you want.
                </small>
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              </div>

              <div>
                <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
                  <Field
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="switchGroup"
                    id="instagram-switch"
                    value={instagram ? "" : "instagram"}
                    disabled={instagram}
                    className={`custom-control-input ${
                      touched.switchGroup && errors.switchGroup
                        ? "is-invalid"
                        : null
                    }`}
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    htmlFor="instagram-switch"
                  >
                    Instagram
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
                  <Field
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="switchGroup"
                    id="twitter-switch"
                    value={twitter ? "" : "twitter"}
                    disabled={twitter}
                    className={`custom-control-input ${
                      touched.switchGroup && errors.switchGroup
                        ? "is-invalid"
                        : null
                    }`}
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    htmlFor="twitter-switch"
                  >
                    Twitter
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div className="custom-control custom-switch">
                  <Field
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="switchGroup"
                    id="github-switch"
                    value={github ? "" : "github"}
                    disabled={github}
                    className={`custom-control-input ${
                      touched.switchGroup && errors.switchGroup
                        ? "is-invalid"
                        : null
                    }`}
                  />
                  <label
                    className="custom-control-label"
                    htmlFor="github-switch"
                  >
                    GitHub
                  </label>
                  <ErrorMessage
                    component="div"
                    name="switchGroup"
                    className="invalid-feedback"
                  />
                </div>
                <small id="usernameHelp" className="form-text text-muted">
                  The service(s) we should check with.
                </small>
              </div>

              <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox pt-3 mb-1">
                <Field
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="acceptTerms"
                  id="acceptTerms"
                  className={`custom-control-input ${
                    touched.acceptTerms && errors.acceptTerms
                      ? "is-invalid"
                      : null
                  }`}
                />
                <label htmlFor="acceptTerms" className="custom-control-label">
                  By checking this box you agree to our:
                </label>
                <ErrorMessage
                  component="div"
                  name="acceptTerms"
                  className="invalid-feedback"
                />
              </div>
              <span className="grey termslabel">
                <Link href="/tos">
                  <a className="terms" target="_blank">
                    Terms of Use
                  </a>
                </Link>{" "}
                and{" "}
                <Link href="/privacy">
                  <a className="terms" target="_blank">
                    Privacy Policy
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </span>
              <Button
                className="btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
                variant="primary"
                disabled={isSubmitting, error}
                type="submit"
              >
                {isSubmitting && (
                  <Spinner
                    as="span"
                    animation="grow"
                    size="lg"
                    role="status"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  />
                )}
                {isSubmitting && <span> Submitting...</span>}
                {!isSubmitting && <span>Sign up</span>}
              </Button>
              {error ? <Error error={error} /> : null}
              <p className="mt-4 mb-3 text-muted text-center">
                &copy; Notify.is 2020
              </p>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>

      <style jsx>
        {`
          .display-4 {
            font-weight: 700;
          }

          .terms {
            text-decoration: underline;
          }
          .terms:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        `}
      </style>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up managing to do what I wanted in a different way than originally intended, but it works well.

Using the Boolean variables that change value based on whether a field should be disabled, I did an if statement for each one within the Formik onSubmit prop and changed the values within the array at the indexes of the values that should be omitted.

```js
<Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {

            // if the field was disabled then don't submit switch value
            if (instagram) {
              var i = values.switchGroup.indexOf("instagram");
              values.switchGroup[i] = null
            }
            if (twitter) {
              var i = values.switchGroup.indexOf("twitter");
              values.switchGroup[i] = null
            }
            if (github) {
              var i = values.switchGroup.indexOf("github");
              values.switchGroup[i] = null
            }

            const data = new URLSearchParams(values);
            const res = await axios
              .post("/api/signup", data)
              .then((response) => {
                Router.push("/thanks");
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                setError(error.message);
              });
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [FieldArray](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray) component. Its' render prop provides an `arrayHelper` for adding/removing values from fieldArrays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried out ```() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)``` within the ```value={}``` attribute but unfortunately it still didn't remove the values from the array when the field becomes disabled. ```arrayHelpers.remove(index)``` only seems to work when used as a button, from my testing.